# How I can build sign-in to play games without google normal sign-in button

Tags: android, google-play-games

I've a question about google play games services.

My question is why I can't create sign-in to play games without google normal sign-in button ?

I played many games and those games has sign-in to play games without google normal sign-in button.

Do I should build google normal sign-in button before create sign-in play games button ?

Note : I mean about (google normal sign-in button) like below image because I
 dunno what's name that button.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to create  google sign in button to sign-in to play games .

You can have the sign in code onClick of regular button or, onCreate() or  onStart callback method  of the activity

For example :

```
RegulerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override

   public void onClick(View view) {

       startSignInIntent();

   }

});
```

Following link shows you the code for   startSignInIntent() method 
https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/signin#performing_interactive_sign-in

Comment: Did you try above method ? if you do not like it i can give you an other option . Please let me know??